# struts2 jquery grid plugin: set width dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, width, jqgrid, struts2

I'm using the struts2 jquery grid pluggin with

```
    <@sjg.grid
    ...
    id="mygrid"
    shrinkToFit="true"
    resizable="true"
    shrinkToFit="true"
    width= "1000"
    ...
```

This display a table within a division (i.e div="foo") on my page. The "foo" division is fluid changes with screen resolution. What I need to do is to dynamically update the width of the grid to the size of the foo division. i.e.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var foo_width = $("#foo").width();
    // dynamically update mygrid width to foo_width
}
```

Any idea? 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Not entirely sure if I understand the question, but maybe check window size and the width of foo at that point to update the width?

Comment: I've tried the lines below. It doesn't solve the problem, it just messed up the grid columns and pagination.


var foo_width = $("#foo").width();
$('#mygrid').width(foo_width);

Answer (score 1):

Just found out there is *autowidth* attribute in the struts2-jquery plugin:

```
<@sjg.grid
    ...
    id="mygrid"
    shrinkToFit="true"
    resizable="true"
    shrinkToFit="true"
    width= "1000"
    ...
    autowidth="true"
```

That *autowidth* attribute automatically sets the width of the grid to the one of the parent element. Documentation here http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag